# Embedding Python in Visual C++ and runtime error R6034

Tags: visual-studio, python-2.7, python-embedding, mayavi

So over the past week or so I have been experimenting with embedding a python script into C.  I have done this in successive stages.  For one of my first attempts I would call my python script from C and within my python script a 2D colormap would be produced.  This part work quite well.
My next step was to implement 3D visual (more of a 3D surface) in my python script.  I accomplished this with the use of mayavi2.  Now when I run my python script without embedding (i.e. with the IDLE) it works fine a produces both the 2D and 3D visual.  However when I try to embed my script in C I get a runtime error:  R6034.  I should specify by saying that I am using python2.7 (I downloaded python(x,y)) and I am using Visual Studio 2012.
I was wondering if anyone came across this problem and might know how to remedy this issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I've run into a similar problem (though I'm using Visual Studio 2005). I thought Visual Studio 2012 might fix the problem, since they seem to have done away with manifests, but it sounds like it might not...

Comment: I have the same problem developing Euler Math Toolbox with the Networkx library.